# Is there a javascript method to find substring in an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

Suppose my array is ["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"] and I am looking at if "mnop" is part of this array. How can I do this using a javascript method?

I tried this and it does not work:

```
var array= ["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"];
console.log(array.indexOf("mnop")); //-1 since it does not find it in the string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array= ["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"];
var newArray = array.filter(function(val) {
    return val.indexOf("mnop") !== -1
})
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: or `array.some()` if you only need to know wether there is a match or not. Because `some()` can stop iterating as soon as it has a match.

Answer (score 1):

a possible solution is filtering the array through `string.match`

```js
var array= ["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"];

var res = array.filter(x => x.match(/mnop/));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`Array#some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
// ES2016
array.some(x => x.includes(testString));

// ES5
array.some(function (x) {
  return x.indexOf(testString) !== -1;
});
```

Note: arrow functions are part of ES6/ES2015; [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is part of ES2016.

The `Array#some` method executes a function against each item in the array: if the function returns a *truthy value* for at least one item, then `Array#some` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not provide what you're asking before because it's easily done with existing functions. You should iterate through each array element individually and call `indexOf` on each element:

```
array.forEach(function(str){
    if(str.indexOf("mnop") !== -1) return str.indexOf("mnop");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this https://jsfiddle.net/uft4vaoc/4/

Ultimately, you can do it a thousand different ways. Almost all answers above and below will work.

```
<script>
var n;
var str;
var array= ["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"];
//console.log(array.indexOf("mnop")); //-1 since it does not find it in the string
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    str = array[i];
    n = str.includes("mnop");
    if(n === true){alert("this string "+str+" conatians mnop");}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note: your `i` variable is global.

Comment: @gcampbell wouldn't all these variables be global not just `i`? :) see here, https://jsfiddle.net/uft4vaoc/6/

Comment: `i` here is an implied global: people usually write `for (var i = 0;` rather than `for (i = 0;`. It becomes an issue if you have code inside the loop that also changes the global `i` variable.